# kernel of product of group homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $f,g:A \to B$ be group homomorphisms, with $B$ abelian. Then $f\cdot g$ is also a group homomorphism. What can I say about $\ker(f \cdot g)$ in terms of $\ker(f)$ and $\ker(g)$?

Comment: Not much. Certainly anything in the intersection of their kernels will be in the kernel. But it can easily be larger than that (take $g(x) =f(x^{-1})$)

Comment: I think that you can't say anything but $$\ker f \cap \ker g \subseteq \ker (f \cdot g)$$ without further assumptions.

Comment: To make things more clear I think it is better to write $f+g$ (since $B$ is abelian).

Comment: I agree with the previous comments. It could be anything between $\ker(f) \cap \ker(g)$ and $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot say much other than $\ker f\cap \ker g\leq\ker(f\cdot g)$. Indeed, if $f$ is any homomorphism $f:A\rightarrow B$ with $B$ abelian then there exists a homomorphism $g:A\rightarrow B$ such that:

1. $\ker(f\cdot g)=A$. Simply take $g: x\mapsto f(x)^{-1}$, as inversion is a homomorphism in abelian groups.
2. $\ker(f\cdot g)=\ker f$ . Just take $g: x\mapsto 1$.

(I have written these multiplicatively. In additive notation, take $g: x\mapsto -f(x)$ for the first map and $g: x\mapsto 0$ for the second.)